# denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I wrote gitlab-ci.yml file.
I Login to gitlab registry with this command

```
docker login -u $CI_DEPLOY_USER -p $CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
```

and in the next step build the docker image

```
docker build -t $REGISTRY .
```

But When i push docker image

```
docker push $REGISTRY
```

I get this error

denied: requested access to the resource is denied

How can fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

Gitlab is probably not finding any **repository** of the same name as the registry you're trying to push to.

For example if you do `docker push gitlab.helloworld.com/prefix/repo-name`, then you need to have a project `prefix/repo-name`

You can read about more about this issue [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23339)

Comment: Yes try that, it seems to be usually the issue in question

Comment: OpenSorce-Team is my gruop name, is it okay to use it in $REGISTRY for push?

Comment: If your `registry` URL has a valid repository name, I don't think what I'm proposing will solve your issue. You can check in the link I provided though

Answer (score 1):

tag the image with {{username}}/{{imagename}}:{{version}}

docker login

docker push {{username}}/{{imagename}}:{{version}}